# Creating new objects from array to array

Tags: java, arrays, object, unique

I'm trying to generate new unique objects from an array of all possible objects to another array. The idea is that I have 3 classes that implement Region class and they have their own methods. These 3 classes are in my `ArrayList<Region> arr`. I pick a random class and add it to `ArrayList<Region> ALL_REGIONS` in a for loop. The problem is that the object that is added from `arr` is not unique, they are the same. This ca be told by their name. Every Region must have it's unique name and other settings but they don't. So this is the code I have so far:

```
public void generateRegions(){
    ArrayList<Region> arr = Regions.getAllRegions();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    String ntype;
    int regcounter = 5;
    int b;

    for(int i = 0; i < regcounter; i++){
        ALL_REGIONS.add(arr.get(rnd.nextInt(arr.size())));
        ntype = "n" + ALL_REGIONS.get(i).getType();

        b = rnd.nextInt(Regions.getNtypeSize(ntype));
        UI.print("b: " + b);
        ALL_REGIONS.get(i).setName(Regions.getArrayName(ntype, b));
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Region> getAllRegions(){
    ArrayList<Region> arr = new ArrayList<Region>();

    arr.add(new Highlands());
    arr.add(new Cave());
    arr.add(new Oasis());

    return arr;
}
```

`getArrayName` returns a String name of the Region from an array and `getNtypeSize` returns an int, size of the array `String[]` that contatins all names which is not really important just now.

So.. how can I have every Cave, every Oasis unique/as a separate object?

**EDIT: ** Requested getArrayName() and getNtypeSize() methods are below:

```
public static String getArrayName(String ntype, int t) {
    String ans = null;

    if(ntype.equals("ncave")){
        if(t<=ncaveSize)
            ans = ncave[t];
    }else if(ntype.equals("noasis")){
        if(t<=noasisSize)
            ans = noasis[t];
    }else if(ntype.equals("nhighlands")){
        if(t<=noasisSize)
            ans = nhighlands[t];
    }

    //Can happen when t is bigger then ntype size or
    // if ntype string is wrong
    if(ans == null){
        UI.printerr("getArrayNames: ans is empty/null");
    }
    UI.printerr(ans);
    return ans;
}

public static int getNtypeSize(String ntype){
    int ans = 0;

    if(ntype.equals("ncave")){
            ans = ncaveSize;
    }else if(ntype.equals("noasis")){
            ans = noasisSize;
    }else if(ntype.equals("nhighlands")){
            ans = nhighlandsSize;
    }else
        UI.printerr("getNtypeSize: returned 0 as an error");

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: So you need to get back each element in the array as object of its initial type, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
ALL_REGIONS.add(arr.get(rnd.nextInt(arr.size())));
```

Here, you're not adding a **new** object to ALL_REGIONS. Rather, each time you're adding a **reference** to an object in 'arr'.

For example, each time `rnd.nextInt(arr.size())` returns 2, you would add a reference to `arr[2]` to `ALL_REGIONS`. Thus, effectively, each entry in `ALL_REGIONS` refers to one of the objects in `arr`. (In this specific example, one of 3 objects you added in `getAllRegions()`)

Effectively, this means that every `Highlands` object reference in `ALL_REGIONS` points to the same object => `arr[0]`
Similarly, every `Cave` reference in `ALL_REGIONS` points to `arr[1]` and every `Oasis` reference points to `arr[2]`

Something along this line should fix the issue:

```
Region reg = arr.get(rnd.nextInt(arr.size()))  
ALL_REGIONS.add(reg.clone()); // this is just meant to be a sort of pseudo-code. Use a clone() method to create a new copy of the object and that copy to ALL_REGIONS.
```

Comment: I looked at those and found them doing their work correctly but I will post an EDIT: shortly

Comment: @VitalijKornijenko While at it, make your code a minimal example that we can run, and add what output you get and what you expect.

Comment: @jihinpt you can put your comment in comment area cuz it is not an answer. you should delete it in order avoiding to get voted down.

Comment: @Kick: Sure. I'll edit it. Its just that it doesnt allow me to add comments since my points is less than 50. Sorry about that.

Comment: @jithinpt your formatting is too bad. just fix it up cuz you gonna get voted down too

Comment: @jithinpt Okay, I get it now. The only problem is the clone method. Apparently it's a method from `Object` but I can't reference to `Object` when I'm using `Region` instead. I'm trying to take a look at it just now, but if you want you can throw a comment or so about `clone()` :)

Comment: @VitalijKornijenko You needn't use the clone() method defined in Object. You could define one in your Region class. The clone method should create a new object (N) with the same type as the input object (I) and copy all the necessary fields from this I to N

Comment: @KickButtowski Thanks for pointing out the format issue. I haven't posted a lot on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right? You want to cast back to the type of the original object. It is plenty easy to do so, you will use some of the Java Polymorphism concepts.
You will use a function called `InstanceOf` like this

```
Region ob = arr[0];
if (ob instanceof Highlands)
    Highlands newOb = (Highlands) ob;
```